# need help installing sick lms200 sensor software

Tags: command-line, drivers, compiling, c++, make

I have the LIDAR Sick lms200 http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/
I would like to install the driver, but compiling the source ends in error. 
I have tried modifying the compilation flags to be c++11 specific in the Makefile `CXXFLAGS= -g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic`

in either case, I havent been able to compile the source.
`./configure` runs no errors return
`make`
`Makefile:340: recipe for target 'SickLD.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [SickLD.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ae/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers/ld/sickld-1.0'
Makefile:246: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ae/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers/ld'
Makefile:251: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ae/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers'
Makefile:246: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ae/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++'
Makefile:362: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`

Make throws a bunch of warnings about c++11 depreciated code, I dont care about any of that, im just trying to make this LIDAR work. 
My OS is Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Comment: I doubt that any package that was last updated in 2010 will ever compile on any modern kernel and gcc combination. I suggest that you look elsewhere.

Comment: I found some typos in the make files or file names, several directories down. now im looking into some other issues. what library includes getdtablesize(),?

Comment: Please see: https://linux.die.net/man/2/getdtablesize That suggests that it's part of *glibc*.